# Laravel websocket wont trigger event from vue front end

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-websockets

I already have setup my websocket connection with pusher. I can fire events at the websocket admin and i can show the output of it via `console.log`. Now i created a new event that if the user adds new product, the table will be updated whenever who is viewing it. But it seems I can add data successfully but the table wont update to other user. Can someone know why my event is not working?

ProductsEvent.php

```
namespace App\Events;
//show only important imports
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use App\Product; //Import my model

class ProductsEvent implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;
    public $product;

    public function __construct(Product $product)
    {
        $this->product = $product;
    }

    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new Channel('Products');
    }
}
```

ProductsControlller (store)

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
      $product = new Product;

      //some validation...
      //broadcast(new ProductsEvent($product)); if i put it here i got No query results for model [App\Product].
      $product->barcode = $request->barcode;
      $product->product_name = $request->product_name;
      $product->price = $request->price;
      $product->quantity = 0;
      $product->category = $request->category;
      $product->supplier_id = $request->supplier;
      $product->save();

      broadcast(new ProductsEvent($product));
    }
```

channels.php

```
Broadcast::channel('Products',function(){
    return true;
});
```

and my vue component

```
created(){
            //when i successfully created the data, 
            i will call getProducts to listen in the channel for DOM updates

            Echo.join('Products')
                .listen('ProductsEvent',(event)=>{
                    this.getProducts()
           })
   }
```

If i call `broadcast` before `save` in my controller, I got something like this
`No query results for model [App\Product].`

I uncomented the `App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,` line in config.php in order for the broadcast to work.

Comment: this is much too much code. isolate your problem to make it easier to help you. It's unclear what your issue is, and if you are asking a question to do with the flow or an error, and if so which part. just add comment in the line saying //this shows null or your own debugging attempt.

Comment: okay i will edit my question sir @bosky101

Comment: that one sir is that okay? @bosky101

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know why `.join` wont work but I used `window.Echo.channel` i doubt this is the right thing to do.

```
    created(){
            this.getProducts()
            this.getSuppliers()

            // Echo.join('Products')
            //     .listen('ProductsEvent',(event)=>{
            //         // this.products.push(event.products)
            //         this.getProducts()
            //     })
            //     .here(()=>{
            //         console.log('here')
            //     })

            window.Echo.channel('Products').listen('ProductsEvent',(e)=>{
                    this.getProducts()
                    toastr.success('Product Updated')
            })
        }
```